# Kali Linux - Wireless Adapter: airodump-ng wlan0 - Error

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux, airmon-ng

I am doing a project on Kali Linux's `airodump-ng` command. Though, whenever I try to execute this command on a virtual machine (Virtual Box) with a Wireless USB adapter, I get this message as appose to a list of BSSID's:

```
ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Device or resource busy
ARP linktype is set to 1 (Ethernet) - expected ARPHRD_IEEE80211,
ARPHRD_IEEE80211_FULL or ARPHRD_IEEE80211_PRISM instead.
Make sure RFMON is enabled: run 'airmon-ng start wlan0 <#>'
Sysfs injection support was not found either.
```

Is there a way to fix this? If so, please respond as soon as possible.

Answer (score -1):

if your system is kali2.0

you should use the commands:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down

sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor

sudo ifconfig wlan0 up

sudo iwconfig wlan0
```